# How to avoid x axis truncate with d3 bar chart?

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm dealing with a problem trying to draw a d3 bar chart using a viewbox inside div. The problem is that **x axis labels don`t fit in viewbox dimensions and they appear truncated**. Only when I increase height's viewbox into Chrome developer console labels fit.

My code:

```
const width = 1152;
const height = 700;
const marginTop = 100;
const marginRight = 0;
const marginBottom = 30;
const marginLeft = 100;

var svg = d3.select("#divAccesos")
.append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

// Add axes
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")  
.attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
.selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("font-size", "1.6em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
```

And div that contains viewbox is like this:

```
<div id="divAccesos" align="center" style="position:relative; width:80%; overflow: visible; padding-top:4vh; height: 900px;"> 
</div>
```

[image]

Any idea to solve this? Thank you very much in advance! :-)

**[UPDATED with SOLUTION]** The key was increase marginBottom for making room to x axis labels, keeping the same value for height.

```
const width = 1152;
const height = 600;
const marginTop = 100;
const marginRight = 0;
const marginBottom = 200; // before it was 30
const marginLeft = 100;
```

Comment: It seems like the bars are trying to fill the entire size and the labels still don't fit. I can set height to 2000px that result is the same :( I only get it when I change it in the developer console

Answer (score 1):

The viewBox attribute (as is the case for all attributes) wants a string. You're passing in an array.

```
var svg = d3.select("#divAccesos")
.append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0, 0, ${width}, ${height}`);
```